# Host name is not resolved (host cannot connect)

Tags: hostname

I think this is not a usual "hostname not resolved" issue and I don't think this relates to the service I am talking about below:

1. I have a cluster installed with Anaconda's jupyter notebook, the
   notebook is up and its port is up. Basically, jupyter notebook is a
   service running on the host and user accesses it from his or her
   workstation.
2. To access the service, user will need to go to http://host:port
3. On the host, I am able to use http://localhost:port
4. On the same host, when I try http://host:port, I get rejected with
   the error:
   could not connect to host
5. I am able to ping the host from my workstation and my colleague's
   workstation.

   So what is wrong here?

   Thank you very much. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Your title is wrong: your error is "could not connect" and not "could not resolve". Your software is probably listening on the wrong network interface. It listens on localhost and hence you can access it through http://localhost but not through the server name tied to its "true" network interface through its IP address.

Comment: alright, in your opinion, what/where change should I make? Thanks.

Comment: @PasLeChoix just as Patrick described. Your notebook instance is not listening on an interface that can be accessed from outside the host itself. See https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#notebook-public-server  especially the `c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'` part

Answer (score 0):

This sort of issue is normally because the service is only configured for local network.

You can check this by entering the following command in a command prompt:

```
netstat -an
```

Check the output for entries with your port number that has a LISTENING entry.

If it is listening on all interfaces it will have a *.*, or similar, depending on whether it is listening in IPv4 or IPv6, or both modes.

If that is the case, the service will need to be changed to use all interfaces.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I got:
$ netstat -an | grep 8880
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8880              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

Comment: So your service is only listening on the localhost network.  You will need to change the configuration for your service, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

first , please verify the port opening of the server. please telnet from another workstation.

**telnet host port**

if this is not working run the below command

```
sudo netstat -upant | grep <port>
```

there should be a

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:<port>           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

**if there is a 127.0.0.1 instead of having 0.0.0.0 that is the reason for this behavior**

**if you can see the 0.0.0.0 or host's IP address check the firewall setting (iptables in linux)**

therefore, Please change the configuration of the service to listen for any interface or to that particular interface of the host. check your config , there may be a config for localhost only.

*I think this URL will help you for more information:-*

http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html

Comment: Thank you and sweetfa for the diagnosis, I do not have root nor sudo, I will have to engage a system admin to do the check, can you please give a detailed command here so I can pass it to sa? our sa only run whatever commands we give them, so I better prepare that. Big thanks

Comment: actually it my bad , you can run that command without having sudo(netstat -upant | grep <port>).if you can see the 0.0.0.0 or host's IP address check the firewall setting. in that case you have to ask them to check the firewall settings to open that particular port.

Comment: if your using Iptables you can ask them to run --> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport <port> -j ACCEPT.

Comment: This is what I got:
netstat -upant | grep 8880
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8880              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1424/python

Comment: this is the reason , this service is only listening via your localhost (127.0.0.1) . please change the configuration for any IP or your server IP. then it should work. if it's not working you can go for the Iptables or firewall settings.

Comment: please use , given URL in the answer , you can see there is way to configure "Running a public notebook server" under that you can see

c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate how do I request the change? I would need to present the commands for our system admin to execute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69802/discussion-between-prabath-dolawatta-and-paslechoix).